# If condition works but the same made inline doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have and if statement and works pretty good but i want to made the same in the inline way and doesn't works, here's my code:

```
const request = require('request');
const rp = require('request-promise');

let options = {
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/"+ data.entry[0]["changes"][0]["value"]["form_id"] +"/leads",
    json: true,
    qs: { "access_token": token },
};

let firstRequest = rp(options)
    .then( (body) => {
        body.data[0]["field_data"].forEach( (mydata, i, arr) => {

            firstname = ( mydata.name === "first_name" ) ? mydata.values[0] : "N/D";

        });
    })
    .then( () => {
        console.log( firstname );
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.log( 'Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) );
    });
```

Any idea why this behavior? By the way, i am using nodejs with request-promise.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? Error messages? Unexpected value being set to the variable? What is the value of `mydata.name`?

Comment: The "error" is that i get the "N/D" value and if i do the traditional way (not inline) i get the value what i want.

Comment: I turned both versions into snippets – they seem to work identically. Please edit them so that they match what you're seeing in the real code.

Comment: your code works fine what do you mean it dosent work ????

Comment: i just open chrome console copy paste both code one by one and test both are working fine.

Comment: are you running exact same code or is it different from actual code?

Comment: I am using require-promise in nodejs, here es my code:

 let firstRequest = rp(options)
     .then( (body) => {
      body.data[0]["field_data"].forEach( (mydata, i, arr) => {

    firstname = ( mydata.name === "first_name" ) ? mydata.values[0] : "N/D";

      });
     })
     .then( () => {
      console.log( firstname );
     })
     .catch( (err) => {
      console.log( 'Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) );
     });

Comment: The code is illegible in a comment. **Edit the question** and add a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the original question, i think it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found what is my error, in each loop the variable change it's value and that is the main reason why always i receive "N/D" in the firstname variable.